# Multiple, exclusive, conditions in an if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, multiple-conditions

One of the first two statements in the if statement is false but I would like both of the first two statements to be false for the code to NOT run. please help.

```
void change(Shore* left, Shore* right, int ex, int can) {
        if (((ex!=left->lastMove[0]) && (can!=left->lastMove[1])) && (left->hasBoat)) {
```

I also tried the code below and that did not work either

```
        if ((ex!=left->lastMove[0] && can!=left->lastMove[1]) && left->hasBoat) {
```

Comment: please provide a minimal working example ... before the sharks of SO get here :))

Comment: And (`&&`) means the if statement will work if ALL the parameters are true - so if any of them are false it won't work.  Or (`||`) means that the if statement will work if ANY of the parameters are true - so it will not work only if all the conditions are false..  So what you want is: `if (left->hasBoat) if(ex!=left->lastMove[0] || can!=left->lastMove[0])`  First check for the hasBoat and then check if ANY of the other conditions are true.  You could do it in one if condition but it would be harder to read: `if((ex!=left->lastMove[0] || can!=left->lastMove[0])  && left->hasBoat)`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but most of those parentheses aren't needed. You can write that expression like this: `if (ex!=left->lastMove[0] && can!=left->lastMove[1] && left->hasBoat)`. It means exactly the same thing (which is why the second version didn't fix the problem: it doesn't change anything), but, once you get used to the language, it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void change(Shore* left, Shore* right, int ex, int can) {
    if (((ex!=left->lastMove[0]) || (can!=left->lastMove[1])) && (left->hasBoat)) {
```

Comment: Don't just post code with no explanation. Explain the problem and how you fixed it.

Comment: Thank you! that worked. Sorry about that, I'm still learning the ropes of SO.